# Numeric login app does not switch activities?

Tags: android, authentication

Hi I have a basic app for logging in with hardcoded credentials, and I want it to take you to another activity called Welcome. Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.numericlogin;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private EditText login_key=null;
    private Button login=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        login_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    }

    public void login(View view){
        if(login_key.getText().toString().equals("123456")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class)); 
       }
    else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      {
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

   }

}
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Here is the main activity's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.numericlogin.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_key" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="number|textPassword"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:password="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="@string/login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the second activity I want it to switch to when logged in correctly:

```
package com.example.numericlogin;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Welcome {

    public void welcome(View v){
        ImageView picture = (ImageView)
        setContenView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    }

    private ImageView setContenView(int fragmentMain) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the xml for the above activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.numericlogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.numericlogin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name=".Welcome"/>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

At the moment when I launch it it brings up the first activity and allows you to enter input in the login area, but when you click the login button nothing happens. There are no errors in the code and here is the logcat output:

```
07-01 14:11:15.313: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23128): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Check comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you switch between activities:

In MainActivity.java:

```
Intent go = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
startActivity(go);
```

Your second activity class must extend Activity

```
public class Welcome extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.childact);
    }
}
```

And you must register all activities in manifest file.

You are missing this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.testingproj.Welcome"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: And make sure you have extended Activity in class Welcome @user3657381

Comment: @user3657381 are you able to see the toast inside successful login?

Comment: hi no I can't see the toasts either

Comment: @User3657381 you have not registered button's onclick listener. Add android:onclick = "login" for the button in xml file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot set onClickListener for the login button or set attribute onClick with value 'login' in the properties panel in graphical layout preview.

```
    final Button login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform code validation

        }
    });
```